# Integrating $\sqrt{ax^{2}-a^{2}x}$

Tags: integration

How do I integrate the following function?

$$\int \left( \sqrt{ax^{2}-a^{2}x} \right) \, {\rm d} x$$

Comment: @Paul...Yes....

Comment: Integrate w.r.t. what variable(s)? Technically, what you wrote is not a function, just an algebraic expression.

Comment: @RaskoInikov...It's dx...

Comment: My first step would be [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt(a%5E2*x-a*x%5E2)dx), which looks somewhat messy, but then again, WA doesn't always simplify. Also, telling us it's $dx$ in a comment means that users who just opened this post needs to read through the comments to see what's going on. It is better to edit the actual question post instead.

Comment: complete the square for $ax^2 - a^2x$ and go from there. You then use a cos/sin substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $$\sqrt{ax^2-a^2x}=t+\sqrt{a}x$$ if it is $$a>0$$
by squaring we get
$$x=\frac{t^2}{a^2-2t\sqrt{a}}$$ and find $dx$
$$x=\frac{2 \sqrt{a} t^3-a^2 t^2}{a^4-4 a t^2}$$
and $$dx-\frac{2 t \left(a^{3/2}+t\right)}{\sqrt{a} \left(a^{3/2}+2 t\right)^2}dt$$
the result should be $$\frac{\sqrt{a x (x-a)} \left(a^2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a-x}}\right)+\sqrt{x}
   \sqrt{a-x} (2 x-a)\right)}{4 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{a-x}}+C$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner..Will I square it and find dx...?Then it'll be confusing...

Comment: yes this must to be done, this is the Weierstrass substitution

Comment: Can you please briefly explain why you took $\sqrt{a}x$ ... not any other thing...

Comment: this is the so-called Euler substitution

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $x=a\cosh^2 t$ then 
$$ax^2-a^2x=ax(x-a)=a^3\cosh^2t\sinh^2 t=\dfrac{a^3}{4}\sinh^22t$$

Comment: What is "sinh" in your answer...?

Comment: sinus hyperbolic function

Comment: @NehalSamee [Hyperbolicus sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Definitions). That's standard notation.